# DexIndexOverflowException with ant

Tags: java, android, exception

I have a Android Build with a lot of code and third-party libraries. The build gives the famous error below (to many functions/fields).

I know there is a solution when building with Gradle, but we are still using ant. There are some reasons we can not switch to Gradle yet. Does anyone know a fix for this problem with ant?

```
   [dx] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
   [dx] com.android.dex.DexIndexOverflowException: field ID not in [0, 0xffff]: 65536
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$5.updateIndex(DexMerger.java:479)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger$IdMerger.mergeSorted(DexMerger.java:277)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeFieldIds(DexMerger.java:468)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:167)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
   [dx]     at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
```